# Navigate by Tags inside a custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, tags

I want to have the possibility of navigate by 'standard Tags' inside my custom post type 'Car', like the following:

> http://www.example.com/car/toyota
>
> http://www.example.com/car/blue

Of course, this will show only post from `post_type` 'car'. Not standard posts.

I guess, I need a rewriting function or sort, but I am not good enough to start from scratch.

Any suggestions, code, plugins? Or any clue how I can do what?

Here my settings:

I'm using custom post type + specific custom post type category

- post_type: car
- post_type-category : car_sedan, car_suv , car_supercar
- **standard** Tags : toyota, hummer, blue, red

[I'm using the Magic fields 2 plugin.](http://magicfields.org/)

*Note: I do not want to create specific `post_type` tags, because I allready have a lot of tags and a lot of tagged posts.*

Comment: Hi Micheal, welcome to WPSE. Writing questions/answers is much easier if you use the WYSIWG editor buttons, or just the Markdown syntax for formatting. Please also always include links to plugins or themes or any other source that is related to the question. Happy answering and asking :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use the Permalinks.

> Admin » Settings » Permalinks

You could set the 'tag-base' at the bottom to `cars`, and chose a structure like `%tags%`.
I tried this at localhost, and it works.

The problem is, that now all tag-pages have a url with

```
http://example.com/cars/tagname/
```

You wrote, that you use lots of tags, and I suppose, they are used in different post-types.

If this is not ok, I would suggest writing a page-template, with

```
/* Template name: cars page */
```

and create a page called cars, to display all cars-posts with the requested tag.